# Append 0x and comma value for all elements in a columns

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file with 2 columns and each column has nearly 100 elements.

```
00000 4f000
00001 3df56
00002 4fdea
..... .....
```

I would like to change the content of the files to:

```
0x00000, 0x4f000;
0x00001, 0x3df56;
........ ........
```

Is there any unix command that I can run to change to above mentioned format?

Comment: Why do you want to change `000` to `ooo`?

Comment: sorry it was 000 only..Typo..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single line with `awk`

```
awk '$1="0x"$1",",$2="0x"$2";"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :)

```
$ cat file.txt
00000 4f000
00001 3df56
00002 4fdea
```

Code:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)\s+([[:alnum:]]+)/0x\1, 0x\2;/' file.txt
```

Or :

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(\d+)\s+([[:alnum:]]+)/0x$1, 0x$2;/' file.txt
```

Output:

```
0x00000, 0x4f000;
0x00001, 0x3df56;
0x00002, 0x4fdea;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Sed solution that doesn't expect any other input than what you've shown:

```
sed -En 's/^(.....) (.....)$/0x\1, 0x\2;/p'
```

Lines that don't contain exactly eleven characters the center one of which is a space will be omitted from the output.